# How to dermine a newly created record in RIA Services

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-ria-services

Using WCF RIA Services, how is it possible to determine if a record is newly created and attached to the domaincontext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easy: checking the EntityState of the Entity!